# How do I get Apex code coverage statistics when using Salesforce DX & Visual Studio Code

Tags: salesforcedx, code-coverage, salesforcedx-cli, visualstudiocode

I am using Salesforce DX & Visual Studio Code to develop against a sandbox environment.

After running an Apex test from Visual Studio Code, how can I view the code coverage from within Visual Studio Code?

Comment: See [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261788/visual-representation-code-coverage-in-vscode/261805#261805) on how to visually see the class results in VS Code itself

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The easiest way to be able to view test coverage is to have set the `--codecoverage` flag (`-c` for short) to retrieve code coverage when you run the test [command](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_apex.htm#cli_reference_force_apex).

```
> sfdx force:apex:test:run -c -u myOrg -r human
```

> Note that the `-r` output format flag is required when asking for code coverage

## Let's stick that in a file

To save the output so you can go back to it, I'd suggest the following steps.

- Create a directory in your project called "testresults"
- Add that directory to your .gitignore (optional)
- Redirect the output to that directory

Like this:

```
> sfdx force:apex:test:run -c -u blixtar -r human > testresults/testlog.txt
```

If you want to just make this happen always without typing such a long command, if you're on a machine that supports bash, you could add an alias. The one below appends a time stamp so as to not overwrite previous results.

```
> alias dxtestcc='sfdx force:apex:test:run -c -u blixtar -r human > testlog$(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S").txt'
```

Then, to run tests, simply do

```
> dxtestcc
```

##But I'm on a PC

The Salesforce CLI commands are identical no matter the OS. But setting an alias is different.

As an occasional Windows user, I'm slowly discovering that my preferred way to use Salesforce CLI in Win10 is PowerShell (mostly for the sheer number of commands and functions it supports over CMD). For the benefit of Windows users, the command to create the same alias in PowerShell is as follows.

```
> Set-Alias -Name dxtestcc -Value sfdx force:apex:test:run -c -u blixtar -r human > testlog$(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S").txt
```

##But I already ran my tests, what do I do?

Of course if you've already run tests and haven't done the above, it might be nice to see the current state of your org. This could be particularly useful if you want to track unexpected changes in your Sandboxes or Production orgs there there may be more hands in the deployment cookie jar than just your own.

In this case you'll want to query the ApexTestCoverage [object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexcodecoverage.htm) using the Tooling API.

Here's how to do that with all fields:

```
> sfdx force:data:soql:query -q 'select ApexTestClass.Name, TestMethodName, ApexClassOrTrigger.Name, NumLinesUncovered, NumLinesCovered, Coverage from ApexCodeCoverage' -u myOrg -t -r csv > testcoverage.csv
```

That's an awfully long line...so let's break it down.

- Base Query Command: `sfdx force:data:soql:query`
- Let's make that a tooling api request: `-t`
- Name the right org (skip if you have a default scratch org): `-u myOrg`
- Output to csv: `-r csv`
- And the query: `-q 'SELECT'`
- Redirect to CSV: > testcoverage.csv

The actual query I used was as follows:

```
SELECT ApexTestClass.Name, 
       TestMethodName, 
       ApexClassOrTrigger.Name,  
       NumLinesUncovered, 
       NumLinesCovered, 
       Coverage
FROM ApexCodeCoverage
```

I'd recommend csv or json, as the adding `Coverage` to the query reports every single covered and uncovered line rendering the standard output of the Salesforce CLI unreadable. If you just want to see the summary of the number of covered and uncovered lines, drop `Coverage`, and you'll be set.

**Update:**
The CLI and tools teams have been working to improve code coverage across the board so that it is more consistently reported in all places, and provides better information. The team published this [blog post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/04/clearer-apex-commands.html) recently to highlight the changes.

Answer (score 1):

This was exactly what I needed.  I used a slightly different soql query since I wanted the the code coverage for the apex classes/triggers as a whole.  Here's the soql query I used:

```
-q 'SELECT ApexClassOrTriggerId,ApexClassOrTrigger.Name,NumLinesCovered,NumLinesUncovered FROM ApexCodeCoverageAggregate ORDER BY ApexClassOrTrigger.Name'
```