# No code coverage information was found for test run 7070U00000r8Ny3. Set "salesforcedx-vscode-core.retrieve-test-code-coverage": true

Tags: salesforcedx, code-coverage, vs-code, visualstudiocode

In user setting.JSON I am using

```
{
    "salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home":"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_131",
    "salesforcedx-vscode-core.show-cli-success-msg": true,
    "salesforcedx-vscode-core.retrieve-test-code-coverage": true
}
```

in workspace setting I am using

```
{
  "salesforcedx-vscode-core.push-or-deploy-on-save.enabled": true,
  "search.exclude": {
    "**/node_modules": true,
    "**/bower_components": true,
    "**/.sfdx": true
  },
  "eslint.nodePath": "c:\\Users\\e3027618\\.vscode\\extensions\\salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-lwc-45.13.0\\node_modules",
  "salesforcedx-vscode-core.show-cli-success-msg": true,
  "salesforcedx-vscode-core.retrieve-test-code-coverage": true
}
```

But Still I am getting the below error message:

> No code coverage information was found for test run 7070U00000r8Ny3.
>   Set "salesforcedx-vscode-core.retrieve-test-code-coverage": true in
>   your user or workspace settings, then run Apex tests from the Apex
>   Tests sidebar or using the Run Tests or Run All Tests code lens within
>   a test class file.

Comment: Try with this extension: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/232527/how-do-i-get-apex-code-coverage-statistics-when-using-salesforce-dx-visual-stu/334195#334195

Answer (score 6):

I was having a similar issue. I'd added `"salesforcedx-vscode-core.retrieve-test-code-coverage": true` into the user "settings.json" as instructed.

Yet the error message about "No code coverage information" was still appearing.

When I checked the Apex tests side bar there weren't any tests displayed to run.

[image]

Attempting to use the green *Run Tests* button there gave an error about configuring the Apex Language Server. Something had gone wrong with my "salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home" setting. After correcting that (See [Activate the Apex Language Server](https://forcedotcom.github.io/salesforcedx-vscode/articles/troubleshooting#activate-the-apex-language-server)) and restarting vscode the Apex Language Server started. And accessing the Apex tests side bar showed all the existing test cases.

When I ran them the coverage was now available.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Probably the issue might be with the Apex test execution option set in your org.
Please ensure 'Store only Aggregated Code Coverage' is not checked.

I faced the same issue and it helped me.

The discussion thread where I found the solution.
https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/1262

Comment: thx man! this was very helpful

Answer (score 3):

Do exactly as the error says and add `salesforcedx-vscode-core.retrieve-test-code-coverage` to your workspace settings:

```
{
    "salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home":"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_131",
    "salesforcedx-vscode-core.show-cli-success-msg": true,
    "salesforcedx-vscode-core.retrieve-test-code-coverage": true
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding Brian, I have updated as you said and I have updated my question as well but still, the error is still the same.

Comment: I believe when you run the actual test, you have to set a parameter that saves the code coverage.  Look through the sfdx docs for running apex tests

Comment: I have got the this documentation https://forcedotcom.github.io/salesforcedx-vscode/articles/apex/testing and I am doing exactly what is written but it is not helpful at all

Answer (score 0):

You can see code coverage by installing the plugin named [Coverage Gutters](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryanluker.vscode-coverage-gutters):
Once you've installed it reload VS Code (Close -> Re-Open editor)

- Open the Apex class you want to see code coverage for and on the bottom side of your VS Code screen you'll see a small button named Watch(click once - it will display a warning message, please ignore it):
  [image]
- Re-run your test and come back to your Apex class but now click on the 3 line menu on the right-hand side of the Watch button [image]

Now you should see your code coverage as bellow:
[image]

**Hope this proves useful for you!**