# Visual representation code coverage in VSCode

Tags: apex, code-coverage, vs-code

As per answer in this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/232527/how-do-i-get-apex-code-coverage-statistics-when-using-salesforce-dx-visual-stu), in order to get code coverage after running test classes from VSCode, we just need to add "-c" for the sfdx test command as below:

```
 sfdx force:apex:test:run -c -u myOrg -r human
```

I have added

> salesforcedx-vscode-core.retrieve-test-code-coverage": true

to my User Settings to be set as default.

Even though I can get the code coverage in the Output tab, showing the percentage + uncovered lines numbers, I haven't been able to see a visual representation for each class which lines have been hit or not.

This is what we get after running the tests:

```
    ID                  NAME                                 % COVERED           UNCOVERED LINES
──────────────────  ───────────────────────────────────  ──────────────────  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
01p0d000000kCOcAAM  TaskManager                         75%                 66,67,72,74,75,78,79,82,86,87,89,93,97,100,102,105,106,111,114,119,120,123,125,128,129,130,134,135,140,143,144,145,148,193,243,246,248,251,253,257,260,262,265,267,271,274,276,421,461,474,486
```

Does anybody know is it's possible to get code coverage like we get in Developer Console or like the "coverage-gutters" plugin for VSCode, after running Apex Tests?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In VS Code in your DX project, try clicking the three horizontal lines icon in the bottom status bar.  If you have all the configurations setup correctly (which from your post, it looks like you do), clicking it from [image] to [image] should work

For completeness: the only configuration change that you have to do is enable code coverage in "File -> Preferences -> Settings", search for the setting "Salesforcedx-vscode-core: Retrieve-test-code-coverage" and enable it

**Update Oct 2020**

There's a [new video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-fwY2Wyhhao&ab_channel=SalesforceDevelopers) from the Salesforce Developers channel in YouTube that literally walks you through enabling VS code coverage highlighting from start to finish.

Comment: Awasome tip. Thnx

Comment: As Brian mentioned, visual code coverage works out-of-the-box in VS Code, but do remember to enable code coverage in "File -> Preferences -> Settings", search for the setting "Salesforcedx-vscode-core: Retrieve-test-code-coverage" and enable it

Comment: @OscarScholten Please post your comment as an answer since yours should be the best answer, Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Bahman.A I've edited the original answer to make the configuration change more explicit

Comment: In JSON editing mode it's "salesforcedx-vscode-core.retrieve-test-code-coverage": true

Comment: This is WAY too subtle/hard to find!!! But thank you so much for sharing.

Comment: Cna't say I've ever noticed that icon, let alone assumed it was somehow related to dx or test coverage!

Comment: Genius level! Had it all installed but still was using Dev Console to view coverage in color since I overlooked that icon. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the code coverage as in Developer Console (code coverage for each test method) with this extension.

Disable retrieve-test-code-coverage from settings if you use it.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RaffaelePreziosi.apexgetcoverage