# Code coverage button missing in vscode

Tags: vs-code

According to the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/apex/testing#highlight-apex-test-code-coverage) and another [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/261805/34897) I should have a three-bars icon [image: three dot menu] in the bottom status bar which will allow me to toggle view of apex test coverage.

I don't have this button.

Disabling all extensions except the Salesforce Extension Pack had no effect.

How can I go about finding out why that button is gone?

Answer (score 1):

I'm an idiot, I'd hidden the button.

Right-click an empty area of the status bar and ensure "Apex (Extension)" is checked.

[image: picture showing the option to select]