# How to find out the code coverage for classes in different packages?

Tags: salesforcedx

This is slightly related to this question [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/232527/how-do-i-get-apex-code-coverage-statistics-when-using-salesforce-dx-visual-stu) except that I am interested in finding out the code coverage **per package**.

When deploying 2nd generation packages via SFDX to production environments, I want to run an sfdx command to see what the code coverage is for all the test classes in a particular package.

Let's say I have 10 packages that I need to install in a production org. If I get up to the 3rd package, if the code coverage for that single package is < 75%, then the package won't be able to be installed. So, Salesforce somehow knows what the code coverage is for the different packages.

However, I cannot see any SOQL command I can use with sfdx to identify what the code coverage **per package is**. I have looked at the ApexTest object and SubscriberPackageVersion doc [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_subscriberpackageversion.htm) but it seems there isn't a way.

This would be helpful because with automated deployments, one can then run a script to say '*install these 10 packages one by one and if the code coverage for any of the packages is < 75%, then cancel the process*'.

Comment: Although there is no sfdx command (yet) to do this, one could achieve the required result by running *all* tests after each package install and using the --json flag to see the output. 

Using a tool like [Qt][1], my understanding is that the .json output could be read by a script which would then be able to either execute the installation of the following package or, if the code coverage from the test run is < 75% (or whatever target is specified in the script), the uninstall the previous installed packages and terminate the process. 


  [1]: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html

Comment: I meant to say .jq json, not qt. https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Answer (score 0):

This check can be done via Tooling API querying the DevHub that owns each specific package. The object you're looking for is [Package2Version](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_package2version.htm) and you can use either `CodeCoverage` that gives you the percentage of lines of Apex code in the package version that are covered by tests. Or even better you can straightaway use `HasPassedCodeCoverageCheck` which

> Returns true if code coverage tests were run when the package version was created, and the resulting code coverage percentage is 75% or greater. Otherwise, returns false.

An example-command :)

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "Select id, CreatedDate, CodeCoverage, HasPassedCodeCoverageCheck, Name, BuildDurationInSeconds from Package2Version where Package2.name = 'XXX' order by CreatedDate desc limit 200" -t -u yourDevHubUsername -r csv
```